# Checking list of strings and creating sublists for each specific string index

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, sublist

I'm currently going through a list of 5,000+ strings representing images that were presented to individuals.  113 of these images were repeated. My goal right now is to find the index of each image from the list of 5,000 as well as the repetition of these images (denoted by rep_).  So far I've been able to find the index for all of the images and the repetition images.

My goal now is to attach the indexes of each specific image, along with its repetitions, to a dataframe containing the list of 113 repeated images.

This is the function I used to find the indexes:

```
def index_of_reps(rep_list, img_labels):
    rep_index = []
    for i, j in enumerate(img_labels):
        for k in rep_list:
            if j == k or (j.startswith('rep_') & j.endswith(k,4)):
                rep_index = rep_index+[i]
    return(rep_index)
```

I need to modify this somehow so that each time it encounters an image, and its rep_, that a list is created for that image and put into a list of lists. After that I plan to attach it as a column to the dataframe currently containing the list of images.

What would be the best way to create these sublists given my current function?

Comment: just a tip: you want "and" not "&" in the if statement...

Comment: I think I need a sample list of inputs and 'img_labels'.

Comment: The inputs are:
rep_list, a 113 line long text file and
img_labels, a 5026 line text file containing the same 113 rep_list strings as well as those same 113 with rep_ in front of them representing each time that specific image was repeated (ex. Dog.png and 3 rep_Dog.png and I want those 4 counts to be included with the Dog string in the rep_list).  Img_labels has other images that were not repeated which is why I am searching for just those that intersect with the same names as in the rep_list.